# Size of largest prime factor

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

It is well known and easy to prove that the smallest prime factor of an integer $n$ is at most equal to $\sqrt n$. What can be said about the *largest* prime factor of $n$, denoted by $P_1(n)$? In particular:

What is the probability that $P_1(n)>\sqrt n$ ?

More generally, what is the expected value of the size of $P_1(n)$, measured by $\frac{\log P_1(n)}{\log n}$ ?

Comment: Size of the largest prime of $p$ is $p$ itself. Where $p$ is a prime.This is obvious, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take the negation and this is a very well-known question: what is the probability that all prime factors of $n$ are $\le \sqrt{n}$?  The answer is known quite generally: for any real $u\ge 1$, the probability that the prime factors of $n$ are $\le n^{1/u}$ is given by the [Dickman–de Bruijn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function) rho function, defined by a delay-differential equation.  For $u=2$ we have $\rho(u) = 1-\log 2$, as in Ross Millikan's answer, but there is a very easy calculation that gives this particular case:

$$\#\{n \le x: P_1(n) > \sqrt{n}\} = \sum_{p} \#\{n \le x, n < p^2: p \mid n\} = \sum_{p\le \sqrt{x}} (p-1) + \sum_{p > \sqrt{x}} \lfloor x/p \rfloor \\
= x \log 2 + O(x/\log x),$$

where the main term comes from Mertens' theorem on $\sum_p {1/p}$ and the error terms can be deduced from the Prime Number Theorem (or Chebyshev's upper bound on $\pi(x)$).

Here, by convention, $p$ is assumed to only take prime values.  The reason this is so simple is that no $n$ here can have more than one prime factor $> \sqrt{n}$.

The answer to your second question is known as the [Golomb-Dickman constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb-Dickman_constant).  Wikipedia gives it as about $0.62433$, but I doubt anything is known about its rationality, say.

Comment: Very nice, thanks.

Comment: Is there something you could suggest to further read about it?, it feels trivial but I get lost as to why it looks like  $\sum_{p\le \sqrt{x}} (p-1) + \sum_{p > \sqrt{x}} \lfloor x/p \rfloor$ and either how Mertens/PNT give the estimates, thanks.

Comment: @DanielD. If $p \le \sqrt{x}$ then the $n < p^2$ condition dominates and there are exactly $p-1$ multiples of $p$ up to (not including) $p^2$.  If $p > \sqrt{x}$ then the $n \le x$ condition dominates and the summand counts multiples of $p$ up to $x$.

Comment: Thanks again that was useful

Answer (score 10):

In Hans Riesel, *Prime Numbers and Computer Methods for Factorization*, he gives a few approaches to largest and second largest prime factor. On pages 157-158, he gives a heuristic for a "typical" factorization, that suggests the largest gives
$$ \log P_1 / \log n \approx 1 - 1/e \approx 0.6321, $$
$$ \log P_2 / \log n \approx (1 - 1/e) / e  \approx 0.2325. $$
On page 161 he mentions that Knuth and Trabb-Pardo get $0.624, \; \; 0.210$ with a more rigorous argument. This is 1976, Theoretical Computer Science, volume 3, pages 321-348. *Analysis of a Simple Factorization Algorithm*. So I would say you want to get a copy of Knuth and Trabb-Pardo, which is reproduced, with later comments, in [KNUTH](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/aa.html)

He then presents the Erdos-Kac theorem on pages 158-159, finally giving probability distribution curves for the three largest prime factors on page 163. These graphs would be what I call "cumulative distribution functions," being the integral of the "probability distribution function."  These are also taken from Knuth and Trabb -Pardo. Let me make a jpeg.

KNOTE: The table on page 163 of $\rho_1(\alpha)$ agrees exactly with the table of $\rho(u)$ in Erick's link on the Dickman-de Bruijn function. So, I think you have a winner.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: I should have looked in Riesel. I had tried Pomerance but with not much luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestPrimeFactor.html) it states that the probability that $P_1(n) \gt \sqrt n$ is $\log 2$.  The first few rough numbers are given in [OEIS A064052](http://oeis.org/A064052) but there are no references.

Comment: Ah, I missed that when I searched. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Posting my first Math-StackExchange answer...

According to [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm#How_to_choose_B?) of Wikipedia, due to Dixon's theorem, the probability of largest prime factor of $n$ to be less than $n^{1/m}$ is approximately $m^{-m}$ for any real $m \ge 1$.

So probability of largest prime factor to be less than $\sqrt n = n^{1/2}$ is approximately $2^{-2} = 1/4 = 0.25$. To be less than $\sqrt[3]n = n^{1/3}$ is approximately $3^{-3} = 1/27 \approx 0.037$.

I don't know the details of this theorem, I just found this quotation in Wikipedia and thought it might be useful for you. Also I don't know how approximate is this formula.

I tried to check this formula experimentally and wrote Python code for that (using [Pollard-Rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) and [Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) algorithms). Don't know if according to rules it is allowed to post code here on Math-StackExchange, so providing just links:

You can see (run) my code in action [here](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackExchangeMath375270#main.py) (and [here](https://tio.run/##jVVRb5tIEH73r5iqqoAW40IujYSak06n9tGqqntDFlqbwd4YFrSsE1tRfns6s@AYA5EOCYN3Zme@@b6ZpT6ZXaVuXl8zzEE2aY66FCatdbUW6wLpRZboKh@MlqJo4B7Cb148A7o@ws6YuokXC1TBk9zLGjMpgkpvF/xv8fMcSpaikOaUGmyM3SnLutIGtFBZVbYrOSj4zsHb2HxpNAetaF0qcCMfbny49eHOhzCk@8azjnmlQbIHBdui26L0LkEocF09uW2qgB9SGY6mYA6R1z4pnvLgA6W/bOwh@EkhcdZb@E8fcDZjxuqqKITOUr2r0lxsTKXd5f@k51e79VN019jtothWWppdOabIByJy91bvw6XeNzHsHh8aI7bow8mHI0n11QeqlKoblE8rS1v@29annSzQ1jVggKJw7mC7ydwlR53DybtyIYb1BHd8rTWK/dBZwv19i3O84UTpjqNV6wzfuT2ubFyie4TP9PIFQg8@wfI6GXzpbzkDXU6KnGgmZbEAvepLvawUkpS508k1/72rIBfEVgYiN8hqUPJuPD60XdF1guq0UY1viUzUyoekDT9FuGpIrUI0hn3J1bbZ2cjCIwuvmnhE6Xtzi96YYx2IukaVkfHKhtTkY@8OzmUE@letc7JNzMAg9HkQNUO1lI4TDTgf2YmcAI@GgVMcr0caQSBjX2YGPSlyQzOFmau9Vic@kNyOosHAGaLPrq@l4Qzf/mqlXB82e5Kze6jNDjd7zMh/zUcjDdbzi89zx/sD/nFbqHiscUO5yetZxvZMkrDg8Zzbpzc8yfiIsllsb7@83zQUsTfe3bFA02KRX3jKuYq3xuyzRZZJVTaVMlINWrB8D@GoKUtQlWFv6zNxOPByUq74nJpNGmh6@bTKm2QervjrwKzRpygkwtzSsub1GqHT4nroDVL8oRgdQrLNWbi/7@HmGt86ol2Z3BjXggmkwbJxveuuZjr2XGDXVeso2OOJ3Gja8RF1w6lZLC8J49UEAVGyt0XyC3O4ml0PFxfv/NtVpQ5lEzuXlhtjQWo7pA7EiEElrvOj6znedu4/Yo/wuc4/G3MQRQxAtnXEdxKtvAmULQyOTZ5O8FBJ5Sa587xn/uMgzF9ieNbVgebykZaQYt16cXCbvzhB8XCgAbtre3vvwyMDw/BM52pAaJvqes3OlaGvLemVpkqUmKb8AXHStBRSpanTQm5Hefb6@gc) is a copy of my code just in case if first link is broken, second link is not runnable).

Results for 10K checked 64-bit numbers here:

```
Checked nums: 10242
Expected: 1.0: 1.00000, 1.5: 0.54433, 2.0: 0.25000, 2.5: 0.10119, 3.0: 0.03704, 3.5: 0.01247, 4.0: 0.00391, 4.5: 0.00115, 5.0: 0.00032, 5.5: 0.00008
Actual:   1.0: 1.00000, 1.5: 0.51541, 2.0: 0.23203, 2.5: 0.09008, 3.0: 0.03202, 3.5: 0.01021, 4.0: 0.00321, 4.5: 0.00105, 5.0: 0.00038, 5.5: 0.00005
```

Here are pairs of `m` (from formula above) and probability. So Expected (by formula above) is close to Actual (experimental with factoring of 64-bit numbers), especially close for larger `m`. Maybe formula is more precise for larger than 64-bit numbers that I checked or for more amount of tested numbers.