# Probability for composite $n$ to have prime factor $\geq \sqrt n$

Tags: probability, divisibility, prime-factorization, conjectures

Let $\operatorname{GPF}(n)$ denote the largest prime factor of 
$n\in\mathbb N_{>1}$. My computer tests for intervalls $[m,n]$, where $n<10,000,000$, suggests that the probability
$\operatorname{P}(\operatorname{GPF}(n)\geq\sqrt n)$ is asymptotically equivalent with a constant $\approx\frac{8}{11}$.

Can this be proved, heuristically understood or falsified?

Comment: The probability over what? What you are saying seems to more closely resemble the idea that the density of naturals with this property is $\approx \frac 8{11}$.

Comment: The precise limit is $\ln 2$. See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function).

Comment: @DreamConspiracy: the meaning is $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n$, where $p_n$ is the probability that a random integer $\in[1,n]$ has a factor $>n^{1/2}$.

Comment: @metamorphy yes, that is the definition of what I said above

Comment: Thanks @metamorphy! I had the feeling this was known.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375270/size-of-largest-prime-factor

Answer (score 2):

Begin by noting that if a natural $n$ has a prime factor $p \geq \sqrt{n}$, then clearly $p$ is unique for $n$. So let's fix some prime $p$ and consider all naturals for which $p$ satisfies this property. Clearly, these are just all naturals of the form $ap$, where $a\in \Bbb N, a \leq p$. From this, we get that if we fix some natural $N$, then the number of naturals less than $N$ satisfying this property is precisely
$$\sum_{p \in \Bbb P, p \leq \sqrt{N}}p + \sum_{p \in \Bbb P, \sqrt{N} < p \leq N}\lfloor \frac np \rfloor$$
where $\Bbb P$ is of course the set of primes.