# Frequency of numbers with a large prime factor

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753287/prime-number-in-human-genome) which has a somewhat random number plucked from nature with one of its prime factors seemingly unusually large compared to the original number.  It then occurred to me that I really have no idea how common/rare such numbers are.

Semi-formally stated:  For any natural number $N$, what is the (approximate) probability that $N$ is composite with a prime factor $P$ where $P > \sqrt{N}$?

I am aware that:

1. From the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) that the probability that any natural number $N$ is prime is approximately $\frac{1}{\log(N)}$, and $\ldots$
2. Between $P$ and $P^2$ the must be $P-2$ composite numbers with $P$ as a single "large" prime factor,

But it is not clear to me how to get from these to the answer to my question.  Trying to Google it has not been very successful, it just keeps taking me back to the pages talking about the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RoughNumber.html) is helpful.

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375270/size-of-largest-prime-factor) is relevant.

Comment: For the first 100,000 positive integers, 73,322 seem to have a largest prime factor $\gt \sqrt{n}$ though 9,592 of those are prime themselves, leaving 63,730 in your category.  By comparison, $\log_e(2) \approx 0.693$

Comment: $\log 2$; see Erick Wong's answer to the previous question at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/375291/173 .  Roughly speaking, the expected number of prime factors greater than $n^\alpha$ is $\log 1/\alpha$; if $\alpha \le 1/2$ then there can only be one large prime factor, so the probability of having a prime factor greater than $n^\alpha$ is $\log 1/\alpha$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In my comment above $\alpha \le 1/2$ should, of course, be $\alpha \ge 1/2$.

Comment: Some more stats: up to $10^6$, .65316; up to $10^7$, 0.66157, up to $3*10^7$, .66452. The proportion steadily rises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a heuristic calculation (not a proof). The nice thing about choosing $\sqrt{N}$ here is that $N$ can have at most one prime factor $\ge \sqrt{N}$, so the relevant events are all disjoint. The probability that $N$ is divisible by a prime $p$ is roughly $\frac{1}{p}$, so the probability that $N$ is divisible by at least one of the primes $p \ge \sqrt{N}$ is roughly

$$\sum_{\sqrt{N} \le p \le N} \frac{1}{p}$$

(where $p$ is constrained to be prime in the summation.) Now we apply the approximation

$$\sum_{p \le N} \frac{1}{p} \approx \log \log N$$

(again $p$ is constrained to be prime here), which gives

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{\sqrt{N} \le p \le N} \frac{1}{p} &\approx& \log \log N - \log \log \sqrt{N} \\
 &\approx& \log \frac{\log N}{\frac{1}{2} \log N} \\
 &\approx& \log 2 \end{eqnarray*}$$

as Michael Lugo says in the comments.